# Accessing and editing multiple addresses in memory

Tags: c++, memory, memory-address

I want to access and edit multiple addresses in memory.
In case it's vague, the question is: If I used memory scanner and the results were a list of addresses, how would I be able to access and edit them all?
I've already been told to try putting all the addresses in an array, how do I do this?

Here's the code so far:

```
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "Windows.h"
#include <cstdint>
#include <stdint.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int newValue = 0;
    int* p;
    p = (int*)0x4F6DCFE3DC; // now p points to address 0x220202

    HWND hwnd = FindWindowA(NULL, "Call of Duty®: Modern Warfare® 3 Multiplayer");// Finds Window
    if (hwnd == NULL) {// Tests for success
        cout << "The window is not open" << endl;
        Sleep(3000);
        exit(-1);
    }
    else {
        cout << "It's open boss!";
    }
    else {// If Successful Begins the following
        DWORD procID;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &procID);
        HANDLE handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, procID);//Gets handle on process
        if (procID == NULL) {
            cout << "Cannot obtain process." << endl;
            Sleep(3000);
            exit(-1);
        }
        else {//Begins writing to memory
            while (newValue == 0) {
                 /*This Writes*/WriteProcessMemory(handle, (LPVOID)0x04F6DCFE3DC, &newValue, sizeof(newValue), 0);
                 cout << p;
                 Sleep(3000);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take the [tour], especially [ask]. Do not post pictures of text, post text. Make a [mcve]. Describe what you want to achieve. Describe the meaning of the list of adresses. Why do you want to edit them? Describe how you access the list of adresses, the code picutre shows accesses via constants. Edit the question for additional information, do not write the  info into answers to your question.

Comment: `p = (int*)0x4F6DCFE3DC; // now p points to address 0x220202` Huh!? This is why comments should not describe obvious code. Code often changes while comments do not. Then it just raises eyebrows.

Comment: @StoryTeller You're problem is the comment is saying something that's obvious?

Comment: I don't have a problem. I'm pointing out a general failing when trying to "comment the code, so it's better".

Comment: @LEXERA.EXE _`// now p points to address 0x220202`_ That comment is simply wrong and confusing.

Comment: `if {...} else {...} else {...}` It's wrong.

Comment: Ok , I will change those things.(Unnecessary commenting and improper if else statements.

Comment: I have a down-vote to contribute, since this question is a mess. Didn't want to discourage a new user, but if you are going to be rude...

Comment: Not my fault you took such a thing so personally.

Comment: @LEXERA.EXE No one takes anything personally here, but you. Your question and code (and the comments) are a mess, it's left unclear what you actually want to achieve, aso.

Comment: I didn't take anything personally, the intention of the question was stated in the first sentence of the question itself. You've contributed and that's appreciated. I don't know how it's "taking something personally" when all I wanted was straightforward answers concerning the question.

Comment: @LEXERA.EXE Well, at least _"... you don't have anything else to contribute?"_ is a bit going ad hominem. Not a good attitude when asking something here.

Comment: Whatever. I'll try and stop going "ad hominem" or whatever that means.

Comment: @LEXERA.EXE [Ad hominem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hominem) - _quidquid latine dictum sit altum videtur_ ;-)

Comment: @user0042 Not really, but.....have fun with that.

Comment: @LEXERA.EXE Sure I have fun, what do you believe is my motivation attending that site? As mentioned I already make my living with other things. :-D

Comment: Regardless @user0042 I appreciate your help on this matter.

Comment: @LEXERA.EXE De nada! Feel welcomed :)

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly easy. Just use a `std::vector<std::pair<int*,int>>` to contain all these addresses you want to modify along with the value they should achieve:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int*,int>> changeMap = {
    { (int*)0x4F6DCFE3DC , 0 }
    // more address value pairs ...
};
```

Then you can process them in a loop:

```
for(auto it = std::begin(changeMap); it != std::end(changeMap); ++it)
{
    WriteProcessMemory(handle, (LPVOID)it->first, &(it->second),
                       sizeof(it->second), 0);
}
```

Whatever you want to achieve with that<sup>1</sup>.

---

> I've already been told to try putting all the addresses in an array, how do I do this?

If you want to set all the address contents to `0` you may use a simpler construct:

```
int newValue = 0;
std::vector<int*> changeAddrList = {
    (int*)0x4F6DCFE3DC ,
    // more addresses to change ...
};

// ...

for(auto addr : changeAddrList)
{
    WriteProcessMemory(handle, (LPVOID)addr , &newValue ,
                       sizeof(newValue), 0);
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Fiddling around in another processes memory is error prone and might lead to all kinds of unexpected behavior!

Your code may fail miserably at a newer version of that program, where you're trying to apply your cheat codez.</sub>

Comment: You can use `for(auto& it : changeMap)` for syntactic sugar since C++11

Comment: @Garmekain Sure! I didn't want to stress that too far. I'm pretty sure the OP would have enough to do with digesting my answer as it is ;-).

Comment: The answer you gave isn't as hard to "digest" or whatever you wanna call it.

Comment: @LEXERA.EXE Well, then you can simply accept it, if that solves your problem. Or did I misunderstood anything from your question?

Comment: Misunderstand*. Hopefully it does solve my problem. Goob job.

Comment: @LEXERA.EXE Sure, I'm always doing a _good job_. That's what I make my living from as a professional programmer :)